# Monads and liftM

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

I'm having a problem using `liftM`. For `(+)` it works fine, the function
`madd a b = liftM2 (+) a b`gives me the expected result `` Just 5 `madd` Just 7 = Just 12 ``
but now trying it with `(/)` it gives me strange results.

`mdiv a b = liftM2 (/) a b` now the operation `` Just 12 `mdiv` Just 0 `` gives me `Just Infinity`
while I'm expecting `Nothing`.

Comment: Why do you expect `Nothing`?

Comment: Because dividing by 0 is not defined, the best awnser would be `Nothing`

Comment: A monad just determines how a monadic computation can be composed with a function that returns a monadic computation of the same type. With `Maybe` the monadic context is computations that may fail. You still have to define what failing means for your computation.

Comment: So in this case i should add something like `mdiv a b = if (b == 0) then Nothing else liftM2 (/) a b`

Comment: `(/)` is only defined for values of type `Fractional a => a`; the only (built-in) types with `Fractional` instances are `Float` and `Double`, and division by 0 *is* defined for those types: the result is `Infinity`.

Comment: For a function where division by 0 is truly undefined, use `div` or `quot`. Even then, they raise an exception, which you would need to explicitly catch and replace with `Nothing`.

Comment: @Kevin no, `mdiv1 a b = if (b == 0) then Nothing else Just ((/) a b)`, or `mdiv2 a b = do { vb <- b ; if (vb == 0) then Nothing else liftM2 (/) a b }`. check out the types that you get for them (and for your version as well, were it technically typechecks but gets you one constraint that doesn't make much sense).

Answer (score 8):

Monads are not magic, they are just encapsulating certain computational patterns.

```
liftM2 :: Monad m => (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
```

and the specific version for the `Maybe` monad,

```
liftM2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Maybe c
```

There's nothing here about numbers and divide-by-zero errors. All we know here is whether a monadic value is `Just something` or `Nothing`.

This allows *us* to define a safe division function, but it won't do it *for* us all by itself.

Haskell is not an intelligent code-writing AI agent. It is just another programming language where a *programmer*, not a computer, writes programs. And besides, why should it decide *for you* whether *you* prefer a run-time divide-by-zero error to happen or not!

Answer (score 3):

If you start GHCi and attempt the 'naked' division operation, you get `Infinity`:

```
Prelude> 12 / 0
Infinity
```

`liftM2` just enables you perform an operation inside of a monadic context. In the case of `Just 12` and `Just 0`, that context is `Maybe`. It doesn't change the operation; it just deals with variability introduced by the container.

```
Prelude Control.Monad> liftM2 (/) (Just 12) (Just 0)
Just Infinity
Prelude Control.Monad> liftM2 (/) (Just 12) Nothing
Nothing
Prelude Control.Monad> liftM2 (/) Nothing (Just 0)
Nothing
Prelude Control.Monad> liftM2 (/) (Just 12) (Just 3)
Just 4.0
Prelude Control.Monad> liftM2 (/) Nothing Nothing
Nothing
```

Notice how `liftM2` handles the cases where one or both of the arguments are `Nothing`. A function that takes two arguments (like `/` or `+`) can't be invoked if you don't have exactly two values. `liftM2` handles the cases where you have fewer than two values by returning `Nothing`.

On the other hand, if there's exactly two values, it calls the function. When you call it with `Just 12` and `Just 0`, you *do* have exactly two values, and the `/` operation is invoked, yielding `Infinity`.

This is as expected.

Comment: *the specific version* of `liftM2` *for the `Maybe` types* does that ("handles the cases where you have fewer than two values"). this needs to be said explicitly, I think, otherwise it still looks like a magic for the OP. if `Maybe` can do that for the missing values, why couldn't it do just that for 0s as well!

Comment: @Will Ness yes why not..?

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have pointed out why this works the way it does for the `Maybe` monad. But of course `Maybe` is not the only monad. You want this to work for `IO`, parsers, and all the other monads too:

```
foo :: IO Double
foo = liftM2 (/) (return 12) (return 0)
```

What should `foo` return? It can't be `Nothing` because its not in the `Maybe` monad.

You might use `fail`, which in the `Maybe` monad does evaluate to `Nothing` and more generally evaluates to some kind of exception value or else calls `error` depending on the monad.

Of course in the particular case of `12 / 0` the right answer really is `Infinity`. The numerical mavens who defined the IEEE 754 standard did it that way for a reason.